# Why do I get this compile error with GCC 5 and cilk-plus?

Tags: c, gcc, simd, cilk-plus

For some reason cilk_spawn does not work with x86 intrinsics.  I get an error every time I try to combine the two in the body of the same function.  (Note that cilk_for works fine).  If I remove all of the SIMD instructions it compiles and runs fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cilk/cilk.h>

int main()
{
    int w = cilk_spawn sqrt(10);
    __m128i x = _mm_set_epi64x(1, 1);
    x = _mm_add_epi64(x, x);
    cilk_sync;
    printf("%d\n", w);
    return 0;
}
```

here is gcc ouput:

```
gcc-4.9 -std=c99 -march=native -fcilkplus -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.c"
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/xmmintrin.h:1258:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/x86intrin.h:31,
                 from ../main.c:2:
../main.c: In function ‘main’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/emmintrin.h:581:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_set_epi64x’: function not inlinable
 _mm_set_epi64x (long long __q1, long long __q0)
 ^
../main.c:9:10: error: called from here
  __m128i x = _mm_set_epi64x(1, 1);
          ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/xmmintrin.h:1258:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/x86intrin.h:31,
                 from ../main.c:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/emmintrin.h:1025:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_add_epi64’: function not inlinable
 _mm_add_epi64 (__m128i __A, __m128i __B)
 ^
subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
../main.c:10:4: error: called from here
  x = _mm_add_epi64(x, x);
    ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I just noticed that that was with GCC 4.9 but the error message is the same with GCC 5.

Comment: Can you try with gnu99 instead of c99 as the language?

Comment: No difference same error.

Comment: It compiles fine with Intel 15.0.3.  You should file a bug with the GCC folks.

Comment: I seem to recall something about _mm_* functions only being able to run in parallel with other _mm_* functions.   ICC may be better able to determine which processors allow different simultaneous contexts with the -march=native flag.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I am running into the same problem with gcc 6.2. No intrinsics allowed :(

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing cilk creates two functions (wrapper over sqrt and your main) in order to schedule them in different threads, if needed/possible. The issue is that under these conditions the *mm** function are now called indirectly and therefore cannot be inlined, at least not without additional information from optimization analasys stages which you have turned off.

I noticed that you compile with -O0. I suspect that if you compile -O2 it might work since the additional optimization passes will provide the compiler with more information that is needed to inline these functions.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to compile the code that was failing with the same error by specifying `-msse` and `-msse2` flags.

https://www.mail-archive.com/blfs-dev@lists.linuxfromscratch.org/msg00033.html

---

[godbolt link referred to by the following comment](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22intel%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXOID2A6ACwD4AoUSWRVADwA4A2cDAJ3ENPOnmRQFsBDDAXZlwXKigggoAawD0U2SJJMkA8AAoAlCQDeJJIaSqA7kgC8SRTID6aAA78TYJGgCOzDBoCMABi0A3AZGNja83gBMtCBI1BZIYbx2CBg2CPYg9AAs1D4ANEjegcGGcZaJNvxwcGkZ2RrUBdTFRlbStmgAnpBBrfasYBgAZhoARACkcAA6YKMFJi1GzCkwzC6%2BQQC%2BQAAA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g6%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-xc%20-std%3Dc99%20-march%3Dnative%20-msse2%20-fcilkplus%20-O3%20-g3%20-Wall%20-fmessage-length%3D0%20%20-MMD%20-MP%22%7D%5D%7D), required by [current SO "best practice"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319541/224132).

Comment: This problem happens with CILK even when `-msse2` is enabled (even with gcc6-snapshot).  The OP uses `-march=native`.  This doesn't fix the problem with Cilk, only for normal cases of that error message (using intrinsics without the right `-m` options to tell gcc those insns are ok.)  I had to edit the godbolt link that demonstrates the continued existence of this problem into your post, because [SO broke comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319538/common-online-compiler-blacklisted)

Comment: Nice website. I didn't know such thing exists for gcc. Now I see that it indeed doesn't help.